# You take one road and then pick up another. What's the difference in meaning between take and pick up?

Tags: difference

> You're gonna take 25 South to Las Cruces. You can pick up 10 West from
> there.
>
> We take the A14 to Birmingham and then pick up the M5.

I guess the *take* means to choose a road and start to drive on it. What exactly does the *pick up* mean in this context?

I've found one definition:

pick up:
find and take a particular road or route.
"they veered left and picked up the road which ran alongside the river"

So what's the difference between *take* and *pick up* here?

Comment: I see no difference, except that "pick up" suggests a transition. You could use "pick up" even for the start of the journey, because there's a transition there, too. The writer is using some variety. In place of "pick up", they could have written "and then take".

Comment: You pick up something that you find along the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- **"Take"** is a common, neutral navigational term for
  going on a road.
- **"Pick up"** emphasizes the transition to another road, so
  one sort of envisions the junction or on-ramp, and expects to be told *where* that junction is. For example

> Q: "Which road are you going to take?"
> A:"We're going to pick up I-80"

sounds . . . not wrong, but you have a bit of a feeling that the sentence should end in "at Sacramento" or something. The "we're going to take [road] and pick up [other road] at [location]" (like in your examples) is perhaps its most common use-form; or the question form "where do I pick up [road name]?" if you are asking directions.